# should I create dbContext for my models or use existing ApplicationDbContext?

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, .net-core

I'm developing web application using ASP.NET Core. When I use project template Web Application with Authentification:

[image]

ApplicationDbContext class generated:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }            
    }
```

I can use it for my modeles, but maybe it's better to create my own DbContext and don't mix my modeles with user's authentification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, it depends.

Is this a self contained application that your clients are going to deploy on their own servers? If so, then adding the business dtos to the ApplicationDbContext *might* make sense.

On the other hand, if you're building an enterprisey application, you may want to reuse the authentication across many of your web apps. In that case, you probably would want to separate both the authentication and business models into their own class libraries.

Comment: for now I'll use ApplicationDbContext for everything. I found similar question, and this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19904081/240564 looks right.

Answer (score 3):

I always look at the `ApplicationDbContext` the same way as the `SqlMembershipProvider`, I have never added my data access code to it.

`ApplicationDbContext` is something related to asp.net identity and not to my application or business logic, so I always separate the contexts, have my own user entity and link the other `IUser` to this entity.

This works fine with me in case if i need to change the whole security framework with something else

Comment: I would disagree with this, if Microsoft had considered that `ApplicationDbContext` should only contain models relating to authentication, it would be named something like `IdentityDbContext` or `AuthenticationDbContext`. Since it is named `**Application**DbContext`, I think it is OK to insert other application related models there as long as it makes good design sense.

Comment: It is only a default name in a template and should really mean nothing to the design of the application

Comment: @HaithamShaddad if you look at IdentityDbContext ,you will see it derived from DbContext,also if you have Controller that use DbContext and IdentityDbContext  at same time you cannot create instance of both at same time